# Keeping Two People From Running the Same Program at the Same Time on a Shared Drive

Tags: python, windows, exe, drive

I have a pyinstall built Windows exe on a shared drive.  Is there a robust way to stop two different users from running the exe at the same time.  For the second user it could...

```
print('Someone else is running "Blah.exe".  Please be patient.')
```

I was thinking of having the program create a hidden file and test for that file but I was worried someone might hit Cntl-C and the hidden file would stay around and keep people from running the exe.

Comment: I guess I could capture Cntl-C's but there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: You'll probably have to keep some sort of cache on the drive. You could always implement a timeout on the lock, and have the app refresh it if it's still running. Depending on what it does, you could possibly run it as service and let users queue jobs?

Comment: You can flag an `os.open` call to create a file exclusively (i.e. fail if it already exists) and automatically delete the file when it's closed, such as when the process exits or gets terminated. For example `fd = os.open(filepath, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_TEMPORARY)`.

Comment: But you need a directory that's accessible to everyone. You cannot assume you have write access to the program directory. A typical place would be in a subtree of `%ProgramData%`. Create a subdirectory for your program, or "<organization name>\<program name>" if that's applicable. Then create a "Temp" subdirectory for the program and use icacls.exe to grant the right to add files (i.e. write data) and remove files (i.e. delete child) to all users (use "*BU" for BUILTIN\Users). For example: `"%SystemRoot%\System32\icacls.exe" "<dirpath>" /grant *BU:(WD,DC)`.

Comment: @erykson Interesting idea.  I'll try it Monday.

Comment: @eryksun  I think this will work.  If you write up an outline answer I'll give you credit.